# How to read in file paths into a queue that is in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to read file paths from a persistent volume and store these file paths into a persistent queue of sorts. This would probably be done with an application contained within a pod. This persistent volume will be updated constantly with new files. This means that I will need to constantly update the queue with new file paths. What if this application that is adding items to the queue crashes? Kubernetes would be able to reboot the application, but I do not want to add in file paths that are already in the queue. The app would need to know what exists in the queue before adding in files, at least I would think. I was leaning on RabbitMQ, but apparently you cannot search a queue for specific items with this tool. What can I do to account for this issue? I am running this cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine, so this would be on the Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: please provide what kubernetes version you are using and where, is it local or in a specific cloud provider?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited my post to include that I am using Google Kubernetes Engine.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes, they do! Sorry!

Comment: @AdrianoMatos, could you please mark the answers as accepted, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if this application that is adding items to the queue crashes?
> Kubernetes would be able to reboot the application, but I do not want
> to add in file paths that are already in the queue. The app would need
> to know what exists in the queue before adding in files

if you are looking  for searching option also i would suggest using the Redis instead of `Queue` Running rabbitMQ on K8s i have pretty good experience when it's come to scaling and elasticity however there is [HA helm chart of RabbitMQ](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha) you can use it.

i would Recomand checking out Redis and using it as backend to store the data, if you looking forward to create queue still you can use Bull : https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull

it uses the Redis as background to store the data and you can create the queue using this library.

As in Redis you will be taking continuous dump at every second or so...! there is less chances to miss data however in RabbitMQ you can keep persistent messaging plus it provide option for acknowledgment and all.

it's about the actual requirement that you want to implement. If your application wants to order in the list you can not use the Redis in that case RabbitMQ would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever heard about [KubeMQ](https://kubemq.io/)? There is [a KubeMQ community](https://github.com/kubemq-io/kubemq-community) where you can refer to with the guides and help.

As an alternative solution you can find useful [guide on official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/) on creating working queue with Redis